# Find the impulse response to a RLC filter

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a serial RLC-filter for which I should first determine the transfer function and then the impulse response.

I figured out that the transfer function is: $H(s)=V(s)/U(s)$ And my circuit has the formula (Ri(t) = v(t) which is the output, and u(t) is input): $$ Li'(t)+\frac{1}{C}\int_0^ti(t)dt+Ri(t)=u(t)$$ then by transforming it with Laplace and rearranging it I get:

$$H(s) = \frac{R}{Ls+\frac{1}{Cs}+R}$$

But how do I get the impulse response for that? I think that I should transform H(s) back to t-domain again, but I don't really know how to do that when the expression is as it looks above.

EDIT

Completing the square of the denominator gives me this:

$$H(t) = \frac{Rs}{L(s+\frac{R}{2L})^2+\frac{1}{C}-\frac{R^2}{4L}}$$

But how can I use this?

Comment: A good first step is to complete the square in the denominator. Then take a look at a table of Laplace transforms and see if anything useful jumps out at you.

Comment: Ok, so I complete the square (I update the question), but I don't really know what to do then...

Comment: With your frequency-domain function in that form, a glance to Wikipedia's [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) of Laplace transforms gives two entries in particular which together give the time-domain function...

Comment: Ok, so I see a lot of entries that might match, it all depends on how I am allowed to treat the constants R, L and C. What should I do with them?

Comment: They're all constants, so it's just a matter of arranging things nicely. It may be useful to write things in terms of the constants $\alpha=R/2L$ and $\omega_d^2=1/LC-(R/2L)^2$ (notation that I'm stealing from Wikipedia's page on RLC circuits.)

Comment: Ok, so I think that I can rewrite it like this: $Rs\frac{\omega}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}\frac{1}{\omega}$ then the middle fraction matches an entry in the transform table, and the last term is just a constant, but how about Rs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17719/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-theva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me fill in my comments regarding why the inverse Laplace transform of $$H(s)=\frac{R}{Ls+\frac{1}{Cs}+R}=\frac{Rs/L}{(s+R/2L)^2+1/LC-(R/2L)^2}=\frac{2as}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}$$ (where I've used the definitions from my comments and theva's answer) can't quite be

$$H(t)=\frac{a}{2}e^{-at}\cos(\omega t)u(t)-ae^{-at}\sin(\omega t)u(t)\frac{1}{\omega}.$$
The big red flag is seen by inspecting units: The only dimensionful part of the first term is $a$ (units of frequency), whereas the second term has $1/\omega$ as well. So the first term has units of frequency, but the second is dimensionless; these aren't compatible, so at least one of them must be flawed.

To see which is right, note that the $s$-domain transfer function is a ratio of input and output voltages. On the other hand, taking a Laplace transform to get from $t$- to $s$-domain involves integrating $H(t)$ over all times. Thus $H(t)$ must have units of frequency for $H(s)$ to be dimensionless. So there must have been an algebra error for the second coefficient.

To resolve this, note that $s=(s+a)-a$ and therefore

$$H(s)=2a\frac{(s+a)-a}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}=2a\left[\frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}-\frac{a}{\omega}\frac{\omega}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}\right].$$ We can recognize these from Wikipedia's table of Laplace transforms as those of exponentially decaying cosine and sine waves respectively. Consequently one has

$$H(t)=2a e^{-at}\left[\cos \omega t-\frac{a}{\omega}\sin \omega t\right]u(t).$$
Since $a/\omega$ is dimensionless, the units of $H(t)$ are correctly those of $a$ i.e. frequency.

For independent cross-checks, it's helpful to take limiting values. For instance, consider the non-damping limit $\omega\to 0$. Then $$H(s)=2a\dfrac{(s+a)-a}{(s+a)^2}=2a\left[\frac{1}{s+a}-\frac{a}{(s+a)^2}\right].$$ This is the Laplace transform of $H(t)=2ae^{-at}(1-at)u(t)$, which agrees with the limiting form of the $H(t)$ obtained above. One can also check that the initial and final value theorems for $H(t)$ are satisfied:

$$\lim_{t\to0^+}H(t)=\lim_{s\to \infty}s H(s)=2a,\quad \lim_{t\to\infty}H(t)=\lim_{s\to 0}s H(s)=0.$$ The first check is especially helpful since it catches any missing factors in the first term.

Answer (score 1):

So I got the expression:
$$H(t) = \frac{Rs}{L(s+\frac{R}{2L})^2+\frac{1}{C}-\frac{R^2}{4L}}$$
And then I divide everything by L and break things out until I get this:
$$\frac{Rs}{L}\frac{1}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}$$ where $ a=\frac{R}{2L}$ and $\omega^2=\frac{1}{CL}-(\frac{R}{2L})^2$

I can then rewrite it again as:
$$\frac{a}{2}\frac{s+a}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}-a\frac{\omega}{(s+a)^2+\omega^2}\frac{1}{\omega}$$
And from here we have two parts depending on s, which fits in to two of the entries in the Laplace transform table at Wikipedia.

Transforming back to t domain gives this:
$$\frac{a}{2}e^{-at}\cos(\omega t)u(t)-ae^{-at}\sin(\omega t)u(t)\frac{1}{\omega}$$

Comment: The form is right, though the coefficients look a bit off. Here's two cross-checks: 1) Are the units of each term sensible? (Yours don't have the same units---red flag!) 2) Try checking a special simple case. The non-damping $\omega=0$ is an obvious choice with a simple inverse transform.

Comment: I don't understand, a and $\omega$ are substitutes for $\frac{R}{2L}$ and $\frac{1}{CL}-(\frac{R}{2L})^2$, aren't they the same coefficients as before then?